# Richard Herd (V mini-series, Star Trek, SeaQuest 2032, etc.)

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

Veteran character actor Richard Herd [passed away in May at the age of 87](https://www.cnn.com/2020/05/26/entertainment/richard-herd-obit/index.html).  He played a wide range of roles both in and out of the sci-fi genre.   Some of his more memorable science fiction performances included the Visitor "John" in *V*, and Admiral Owen Paris in the *Trek* universe.   Perhaps his best known role outside the genre was as George Constanza's boss "Wilhelm" on *Seinfeld*.

[image]

[image]